# FAT filesytem and flash endurance

Tags: flash, storage, wear-leveling

I am considering replacing a SD card in a tiny embedded system  (Cortex M4 running a RTOS) by some kind of dedicated flash storage chip. However, I am worried about the chip's endurance.

The embedded system uses [FATfs](http://elm-chan.org/fsw/ff/00index_e.html) and writes about 100 bytes about once every 1 minute. My understanding is that this use case is ok in a SD card: that's about 2 block writes every minute, so 10 million block writes over the product's 10 year life. That seems reasonable if I use a SD card with 40k 128kB blocks and about 1000 writes per block.

However, this assumes some kind of wear levelling, since a few disk sectors will be overwritten much more. The FAT data structures come to mind.

My question is, how would I go about replacing this SD Card by a flash chip like [this](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/949/w25q32jv_revg_03272018_plus-1489806.pdf)? I'm particularly worried because I see no mention of wear leveling in the datasheets of flash chips. Should I migrate to another filesystem? Write raw bytes? Buy a chip with built-in wear leveling?

Comment: Check FRAM chips, they allow billions and billions of write/erase cycles (10^12 for a basic FRAM chip, can be up to 10^15)

Comment: There is indeed no wear leveling in a typical SPI flash.  If you are going to be changing the data often, you should use a different type of filesystem than FAT, perhaps something journaling.  If the only reason to have a large capacity is so that you can walk a small amount of data around for wear leveling, then yes, FRAM could make sense.  But FRAM capacities are small compared to SPI flash which are small compared to SD - big problem with SD is not knowing what you will actually get in terms of behavior.

Comment: @Wheatley unfortunately I still need to keep about 1MB of rolling log at any time, so a FRAM chip would be way too expensive

Comment: "I am considering replacing a SD card in a tiny embedded system (Cortex M4 running a RTOS) by some kind of dedicated flash storage chip." - Why?

Answer (score 1):

This is a NOR flash chip. NOR flash has lower endurance, but is more reliable as long as you stay within the limits. It is very appropriate for data that don't change much, but for which you can't really afford a bad block (firmware code, configuration data, ...). It isn't very appropriate for logging data, which implies continuous writes. Such NOR flash typically don't include any wear leveling layer, indeed (because they are, well... used in applications with few writes, so manufacturer assume it isn't generally needed, and it takes quite a bit of silicon logic).

I doubt you can find such a NOR flash chip with built-in wear-leveling anywhere.

**BUT**... Don't loose hope...

The thing is, what wears the chip is *erasing* data. Not really writing it. An erased block will read as all 'FF' bytes (all bits to '1'). Writing it just sets the bits you want to '0'. You can write the same sector multiple times, flipping some of the '1' bits to '0' each time. Erasing the sector will revert all the bits to '1'.

So, for data logging, it is quite possible to imagine some custom scheme where you write your 100 bytes each minute in sequence, each time using a "fresh" block of 100 bytes (by writing the same sector multiple times) and erasing sectors only when you don't have fresh blocks anymore. You also need to keep track of the location of the "latest" written block too, and you can do this also by flipping some bits from '0' to '1' in a particular "index" sector (which you'll also write multiple times without erasing between each writes).

This keeps the number of erasings to a strict minimum (eventually at the expense of some room temporarily taken by outdated data), and that is what will save the endurance.

That can be quite easy to implement depending on the pattern of writings you have to support. However, for something really dynamic (with files of potentially any size, that can be randomly written), it can quickly become complicated. But rather often, the needs are much simpler than this.

Comment: thanks, that sounds a lot of fun but unfortunately also a lot of rewritting. One question: you mentioned NOR chips in your answer (that's the option I chose in the question). Would things be different if I chose a similarly priced NAND flash? Like, say, [this one](https://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Winbond/W25N01GVSFIG?qs=sGAEpiMZZMsIA2dzklOPMze%252BFs5z9XFVtoGMDIluMg9oQrB3XFYh8Q%3D%3D) ?

Comment: One advantage with NAND is that the endurance is typically much better. But the W25N01GV datasheet claims 100,000 erase-write cycles, which is the same as the W25Q32JV chip you initially suggested. You'll have a much bigger capacity, which can mitigate the need for erasing, but you can't just put a regular FAT without wear leveling on this and call it a day. In addition, such NAND flash requires you to manage ECC status and invalid blocks in your OS (see datasheet), and this is not trivial either. In the end, NOR flash is probably easier to use, provided that your write pattern is simple.